# How to find the location of database created using HTML5?

Tags: sqlite, html, blackberry-playbook, blackberry-webworks, web-sql

I am developing a playbook app, where I am creating multiple databases. Can I get the location of the file/db created. I need to delete that Database, but I couldn't find a way to drop it, so I am planning to delete the file that it is stored in.

Comment: Why not simply drop all the tables in your database?

Comment: Even if all the tables are dropped, the db will still be there. In the description, it says that he want to remove the db itself

Comment: I realise that. My suggestion is just being pragmatic: it's not straightforward to remove an SQLite database on a device like the PlayBook, so why not consider other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't drop SQLite databases, as you have found (hence my suggestion to simply drop all the tables).

However, if you really must delete the physical db file, I think your best bet is to mount the PlayBook's file system, and then track the file down. This link may help in explaining the file system layout on the PlayBook:

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Tablet-OS-SDK-for-Adobe-AIR/BlackBerry-PlayBook-File-System-Layout/ta-p/773327

Comment: Thanks for the response. Now I am dropping all the tables and not showing its reference. I believe if I drop all the atbles, it won't consume much memory.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the OS and browser you are using, I have no experience with Playbook and its browser, but for example under Windows XP and using Firefox it's stored on:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\YOURPROFILE
```

and in Chrome there are two possible places:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\
```

There you have LocalStorage and Databases folders.

Hope it helps